# Which plotting library does this plot belong to?

Tags: matplotlib, plot

Which plotting library does this plot belong to?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a combination of normal line plots and a [boxplot, see matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/boxplot_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-boxplot-demo-py).

Comment: Seaborn's [pointplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html), with the `capsize=` parameter set.

Comment: Thank you very much @JohanC. Just as you said, its a pointplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very good at ploting grpahs but this is how I came up with what I was looking for:

```
# Import libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np


data_dict = {'Best fit': [395.0, 401.0, 358.0, 443.0, 357.0, 378.0, 356.0, 356.0, 403.0, 380.0, 397.0, 406.0, 409.0, 414.0, 350.0, 433.0, 345.0, 376.0, 374.0, 379.0, 9.0, 13.0, 10.0, 13.0, 16.0, 12.0, 6.0, 11.0, 20.0, 10.0, 12.0, 11.0, 15.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 15.0, 10.0, 8.0, 18.0, 864.0, 803.0, 849.0, 858.0, 815.0, 856.0, 927.0, 878.0, 834.0, 837.0, 811.0, 857.0, 848.0, 869.0, 861.0, 820.0, 887.0, 842.0, 834.0, np.nan], 'MDP': [332, 321, 304, 377, 304, 313, 289, 314, 341, 321, 348, 334, 361, 348, 292, 362, 285, 316, 291, 318, 3, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 8, 6, 4, 0, 8, 1, 4, 0, 9, 5, 3, 8, 770, 770, 819, 751, 822, 842, 758, 825, 886, 830, 774, 839, 779, 821, 812, 850, 822, 786, 874, 831], 'Q-Learning': [358, 329, 309, 381, 302, 319, 296, 315, 343, 318, 338, 336, 360, 357, 299, 363, 287, 337, 301, 334, 3, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 8, 6, 4, 0, 8, 1, 4, 0, 9, 5, 3, 8, 771, 833, 757, 837, 831, 784, 806, 890, 843, 775, 838, 776, 824, 830, 834, 827, 791, 868, 816, 806], 'parametrized_factor': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]}
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

# figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

ax = sns.pointplot(y="Best fit", x="parametrized_factor",   data=data2, linestyles='-.', color='g', capsize=.1, scale=.2,  errwidth=.5)
ax = sns.pointplot(y="MDP", x="parametrized_factor", data=data2, linestyles='-',  color='r', capsize=.12, scale=.2, errwidth=.5)
ax = sns.pointplot(y="Q-Learning", x="parametrized_factor", data=data2, linestyles=':',  color='k', capsize=.15, scale=.5, errwidth=.5)


ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
labels = ax.legend(['BestFit', 'MDP', 'Q- Learning']), colors = ['green', 'red', 'black']
i = 0
for l in labels.get_texts():
    l.set_color(colors[i])
    i+=1


# ADDED: Remove labels.
ax.set_ylabel('Rejection rate')    
ax.set_xlabel('Parametrized factor')

plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='12') # for legend text
plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_title(), fontsize='12') # for legend title

plt.show()
```

I still have not figure out how to change the color of the marks on the legend.